# Add Strings to queue recursively using Python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am reading a file with some words using python, adding all items to a queue and then performing operation `a` using `doWork()` method. I am trying to figure out, how can I add the results performed in `a` operations back to the same queue to perform `a` again on the result itself. The loop needs to stop once the `q` is empty and it does eventually since the operation `a` may or may not return the result.

I hope this makes some sense. :P

```
concurrent = 20

def doWork():
    while True:
        word = q.get()
        lol = getStatus(word)
        q.task_done()


def getStatus(word):
    #results another word on which this operation has to be performed.



q = Queue(concurrent * 2)

for i in range(concurrent):
    t = Thread(target=doWork)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

try:
    for words in open('words.txt' ,'r'):
        q.put(words.strip())
    q.join()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: why not have `getStatus` do the action recursively in the firstplace? why involve the queue in it? Once the queue is empty it will `join`, unless you've already inserted new items (and the queue won't know any better otherwise).

Comment: Did you try to  put stuff on the queue in either `doWork` or `getStatus`?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid a call to q.put() from inside the worker thread.
Why not simply call q.put(get_status(word))

I would disagree with the suggestion by Ofer Sadan, due to the fact that you could starve the other threads, if a single word has an extensive sub-graph in terms of the number of descendant words. 

BTW is getStatus blocking?

Comment: So, for some reason when I try to call q.put() from doWork() function, the program stops after a few iterations. I can't call it from getStatus, as I am not sure how it will affect multiple threads and may starve.